# Terrible electric guitar resonance

Tags: guitar, resonance

My guitar started giving me some serious whine recently (never before). It seems to mostly happen when I play the 'D' chord. I have contacted Schecter, and they seem to think, after watching my video (above), that it is NOT the PUs, but that the sound is resonating. This is very frustrating to me, and I would like any advice to fix it. I can't use any of my overdrive/distortion pedals anymore, and my onboard amp distortion isn't any better. I can have my Gain nearly at zero and it still whines. This doesn't happen at all on clean.

Things I have already tried:

switch cables

change strings

lowered PUs

changed PU battery

tried multiple amps

Comment: does this happen at all when not amplified? I thought it might be a analog (spring) reverb or loose component problem, but you say you tried different amps. Try and identify the exact note (not chord) that makes this happen, and then work from there. If something in the guitar is resonating, it will happen without amplification. I note that there is a preamp in that guitar, so if it isn't the pickups, its the preamp.

Comment: yes it does make this sound when not plugged into anything, thanks for that new evidence! if I do happen to find a specific note, not chord, then what?

Comment: If you can narrow down the note it will help you reproduce it more reliably. Put your ear close while unplugged and localize the sound. This can be the pickup covers, loose wires, the nut on the tension rod. I had an acoustic where a 1 inch section of the binding kerf was vibrating with A and the paper label had a bubble in it that vibrated like a drum at certain odd resonances

Comment: If there is an actual preamp in this, it might still be an electric squeak. Also if there is a spring in the toggle switch, you might try and mechanically dampen it. It really does sound like a sort of reverb, unless that is a plate echo from the recording

Comment: What happens if you put some felt or some thing to damp the string areas above the nut and behind the bridge? Also, if you mute the strings in a different place in the neck the ringing sound doesn't change?

Comment: yes, yours and DrMayhem below have solved my problem.. nothing happened when dampening the nut area, but all was solved with the bridge! thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it links to a private video, and so is of no use.

Comment: @Kaz Although the video is dead, I think the question still works without it.

Comment: @Aaron I see that OP basically acknowledged that Dr Mayhem's answer worked for him, without accepting the answer.

Comment: @Kaz, I did accept the answer.. I see the green check next to the answer. Also, the video was made "Private" by YouTube as some sort of security update. I have made it 'Unlisted' again, so hopefully it shows back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Todd's comment is right. This sounds a lot to me like the symptom I have on my twin neck SG. Whatever I play I get the same nasty squeak/ringing noise. I researched it, and found [wolf tones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_tone) on acoustic instruments - especially cellos so thought I'd do some checking.

It turns out the structure of the bridge and tail seemed to encourage resonance at this frequency, in two of the short tails of strings behind the bridge.

The solution for me was to add a rubber damper to the strings behind the bridge. Instant, and very cheap as we had the rubber bands in the house anyway.

[image]

Comment: what exactly did you do with the rubber bands?

Comment: Intertwined them between the strings behind the bridge. I'll get a picture and update my answer

Comment: WOW.. your suggestion worked! I put a sock in that spot behind the bridge, and BOOM, no scream.. You just saved me packing up and sending my baby to Schecter for warranty work.. thanks again!

Comment: Brilliant! I am glad - I honestly was baffled when it happened to me, until I tracked down that wolf tone article. This is simple and effectively free (my daughter plaited the rubber bands)